# CSS - Como fazer referência a outro Combobox?

Tags: jquery, css

Caros, tenho 2 combobox autocomplete em cascata para Estado e Cidade. Quando troco o tamanho no CSS, muda o tamanho dos 2 combobox e preciso mudar de apenas 1.
Utilizo o código de exemplo do [JQuery-UI](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) e o seguinte CSS:

```
.custom-combobox-input {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 186px;
  height: 24px;
  border: thin #1E56A0 solid;
  padding-left: 5px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="cmbestado">
  <select id="selestado" name="selestado" ></select>
</div>

<div id="cmbcidade">
  <select id="selcidade" name="selcidade" ></select>
</div>
```

Não entendo muito de CSS, como fazer referência ao segundo combo?

Acho que podem entender melhor no seguinte exemplo que usei de base: https://jsfiddle.net/mindlessbaby/zbjk1ss1/70/

Comment: Sobre o "combobox" na verdade é de melhor compreensão chama-lo de `select` ou então `dropdown` que é um `select` personalizado do jQuery. Pois o `select` é o elemento responsável por atuar desta forma no HTML. Outra coisa é que aparentemente o seu html está incompleto, pois você referencia a classe `.custom-combobox-input` porém não utiliza no seu código html disponibilizado aqui na sua pergunta. Forneça o uma fração maior do código para que possa obter respostas.

Comment: Todavia, uma forma de referenciar o segundo `select`, seria através deste seletor (baseado no html da sua pergunta): `select[name=selcidade] { }` ou então pelo id: `#cmbcidade { }`

Comment: Usando o código de exemplo do JQuery-UI na verdade é usado um campo INPUT (onde pode ser digitado os valores e que é buscado no JSON) e o JQuery lista como se fosse um select. Acho que voces poderão entender melhor no seguinte exemplo em que usei de base: https://jsfiddle.net/mindlessbaby/zbjk1ss1/70/

Comment: Dessa forma que você apresentou no fiddle, acredito que utilizar `.custom-combobox-input:nth-child(1)` para a combo de estado e `.custom-combobox-input:nth-child(2)` para a combo de cidade seria uma opção.

Answer (score 0):

Os `combobox` são criado pelo jQuery de forma assíncrona. Neste caso, você pode alterar a largura de qualquer um deles após a função que os cria terminarem.

Você pode fazer isso incluindo uma linha em jQuery:

```
$(".custom-combobox-input:eq(1)").css("width","400px");
```

Onde `:eq(1)` é o segundo `combobox` (o primeiro seria `:eq(0)`).

Adicione o código no local indicado abaixo pela seta:

```
$(function () {
    $("#one").append($('<option selected></option>').val('1').html('1'));

    $("#one").append($('<option></option>').val('2').html('2'));

    $("#one").combobox({
        select: function (event, ui) {
            updateTwo($(this).val());
        }
    });

    // added- update one box value and refresh ui -BD
    $("#two").combobox();
    $("#one").val("1").combobox("refresh");
    updateTwo($("#one").val());

   $(".custom-combobox-input:eq(1)").css("width","400px"); // ←
});
```

**Veja funcionando:**

```js
(function ($) {
    $.widget("custom.combobox", {
        _create: function () {
            this.wrapper = $("<span>")
                .addClass("custom-combobox")
                .insertAfter(this.element);

            this.element.hide();
            this._createAutocomplete();
            this._createShowAllButton();
        },

        _createAutocomplete: function () {
            var selected = this.element.children(":selected"),
                value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

            this.input = $("<input>")
                .appendTo(this.wrapper)
                .val(value)
                .attr("title", "")
                .addClass("custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left")
                .autocomplete({
                delay: 0,
                minLength: 0,
                source: $.proxy(this, "_source")
            })
                .tooltip({
                tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
            });

            this._on(this.input, {
                autocompleteselect: function (event, ui) {
                    ui.item.option.selected = true;
                    this._trigger("select", event, {
                        item: ui.item.option
                    });
                },

                autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
            });
        },

        _createShowAllButton: function () {
            var input = this.input,
                wasOpen = false;

            $("<a>")
                .attr("tabIndex", -1)
                .attr("title", "Show All Items")
                .tooltip()
                .appendTo(this.wrapper)
                .button({
                icons: {
                    primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                },
                text: false
            })
                .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
                .addClass("custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right")
                .mousedown(function () {
                wasOpen = input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible");
            })
                .click(function () {
                input.focus();

                // Close if already visible
                if (wasOpen) {
                    return;
                }

                // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                input.autocomplete("search", "");
            });
        },

        _source: function (request, response) {
            var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
            response(this.element.children("option").map(function () {
                var text = $(this).text();
                if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text))) return {
                    label: text,
                    value: text,
                    option: this
                };
            }));
        },

        _removeIfInvalid: function (event, ui) {

            // Selected an item, nothing to do
            if (ui.item) {
                return;
            }

            // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
            var value = this.input.val(),
                valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
                valid = false;
            this.element.children("option").each(function () {
                if ($(this).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase) {
                    this.selected = valid = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });

            // Found a match, nothing to do
            if (valid) {
                return;
            }

            // Remove invalid value
            this.input.val("")
                .attr("title", value + " didn't match any item")
                .tooltip("open");
            this.element.val("");
            this._delay(function () {
                this.input.tooltip("close").attr("title", "");
            }, 2500);
            this.input.autocomplete("instance").term = "";
        },
        // added- inserted refresh function -BD
        refresh: function () {
            selected = this.element.children(":selected");
            this.input.val(selected.text());
        },
        _destroy: function () {
            this.wrapper.remove();
            this.element.show();
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

$(function () {
    $("#one").append($('<option selected></option>').val('1').html('1'));

    $("#one").append($('<option></option>').val('2').html('2'));

    $("#one").combobox({
        select: function (event, ui) {
            updateTwo($(this).val());
        }
    });

    // added- update one box value and refresh ui -BD
    $("#two").combobox();
    $("#one").val("1").combobox("refresh");
    updateTwo($("#one").val());

   $(".custom-combobox-input:eq(1)").css("width","400px");
});

function updateTwo(arg1) {
    $("#two").empty();

    if (arg1 == "1") {
        $("#two").append($('<option selected></option>').val('1.1').html('1.1'));

        $("#two").append($('<option></option>').val('1.2').html('1.2'));
    } else if (arg1 == "2") {
        $("#two").append($('<option selected></option>').val('2.1').html('2.1'));

        $("#two").append($('<option></option>').val('2.2').html('2.2'));
    }

    // added- update second box value and refresh ui -BD
    $("#two").val("").combobox("refresh");

}
```

```css
.custom-combobox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.custom-combobox-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 0;
}
.custom-combobox-input {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <select id="one"></select>
    <br/>
    <select id="two"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: Beleza, boa resposta e concordo que funciona, mas precisa mesmo utilizar jQuery? se ele souber a qtde. de combos que serão criadas e a ordem de cada uma não seria necessário.

Comment: @PauloRoberto Pelo CSS eu não consegui. Acho que o CSS do jquery UI não deixa alterar. Como são apenas dois campos, acho bem mais simples apenas adicionar uma linha e o problema tah resolvido.

Comment: tentou utilizar com **important**? `input.custom-combobox-input:nth-child(2){ width: 400px !important; }` é provavel que funcione, a não ser que haja outro **important** atribuido na `width` deles pelo proprio jQuery UI, dai teria que ver uma forma de especificar mais ainda o seletor, pois quanto mais específico o seletor CSS é, a prioridade é maior, portanto em determinado nível de específico, sobrescreverá o jQuery UI. Eu estou comentando pois estou impossibilitado de testar, o proxy daqui bloqueia alguns sources e fico com problemas em determinados Fiddles.

Comment: @PauloRoberto Já testei com !important, com nth-child, tentei inserir um CSS dinâmico após 5 segundos, nada funcionou.

Comment: Perfeito. Obrigado @ÐvÐ, obrigado a todos. Abs